# Passport.js express views

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using passport and some static .html files. I want to include them as express views or static files. Now I want SOME .html files like login.html to be available for everyone, but the other view files like secret.html should need passport.
I know, that you can use
`app.get('somePath', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {}` for routes, but I want it for **static files**.

How to do it on a non-hacky way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all "*secure*" files share a distinct URL prefix, such as `/public/secure`, you can [`use()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) `ensureAuthenticated` with this path:

```
app.use('/public/secure', ensureAuthenticated);
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

---

Otherwise, the [`express.static()` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) doesn't offer many options for controlling access. For the most part, it assumes all available files from the path given to it are meant to be "*public*."

Though, it does normally refuse to send hidden files, following the *nix standard of a `.` prefix:

```
~/path/to/.secret.html
```

Then, to actual serve it, you can [send the file](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile) yourself in the route you suggested with the middlware attached:

```
app.get('/path/to/secret.html', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/path/to/.secret.html');
});
```

And, you may want to consider moving it out of your `static()` directory,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your second idea doesn't work. [send](https://github.com/visionmedia/send), the lib express uses to send files doesn't find dot files. And I think that intended.